# How to convert the List<Generic> to dictionary select query?

Tags: c#, dictionary, select

This method retrieves the entire data.
I'm trying to switch this method to a method that uses a dictionary but it doesn't work very well.
INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE completed but I'm having trouble with SELECT.

I want convert to the my method like below link source.
https://gist.github.com/thorsman99/e788dd9cce36c26edd9076c9dac288dd

```
public static List<TestModel> GetList(string id, string subject, string UseYN, string createDate1, string createDate2)
    {
        using(SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(_connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using(SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT ID, Subject,  CreateDate, UpdateDate FROM Test";

                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"ID"         , DbType.String) { Value = id          });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"Subject"    , DbType.String) { Value = subject     });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"CreateDate1", DbType.String) { Value = createDate1 });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"CreateDate2", DbType.String) { Value = createDate2 });

                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                List<TestModel> list = new List<TestModel>();

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    TestModel item = new TestModel();

                    item.ID         =                    reader["ID"        ].ToString();
                    item.Subject    =                    reader["Subject"   ].ToString();
                    item.CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CreateDate"]);
                    item.UpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["UpdateDate"]);

                    list.Add(item);
                }

                return list;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would you like the dictionary to contain?

Comment: `Save yourself from SQL injection` and *how* by using `dapper` prevents this from happening; I bet there's no *facts* that support your case. The user is using `parameters` to prevent this, could you explain? On another note, `where` is your `Where` statement? If your're doing a select query you more than likely need one, based on some kind of id. Then your results could fill a table and or use the reader to get the columns you want...

Comment: @HariHaran Where do you see the possibility of SQL injection here?

Comment: you mean like `var dict = list.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, y => y);` ?

Comment: On another note, `switch this method to a method that uses a dictionary`, if that's the case create a dictionary and change your return type? Currently, you have it as a `list` in which your adding items (TestModel ); why if you don't want that type? For example: `Dictionary<int, TestModel>` and in your routine create one to add to: `Dictionary<int, TestModel> dictReturn = new Dictionary<int, TestModel>();`. Now the question, why a `Dictionary` instead of a `List<TestModel>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved `connection.Open to directly before the`.ExecuteReader` Connections should be open for the shortest possible time. I moved the declare of the Dictionary outside the using block and then the return outside also. This again is to close the connection as soon as possible.

I combined the 2 using blocks to one. Just simplifies the code a bit and saves indenting.

For the dictionary, I used "ID" as the key. I assumed that this was the Primary Key and therefore unique.

```
        public Dictionary<string, TestModel> GetTestModelDictionary(string id, string subject, string UseYN, string createDate1, string createDate2)
        {
            Dictionary<string, TestModel> dict = new Dictionary<string, TestModel>();
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(_connection))
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT ID, Subject,  CreateDate, UpdateDate FROM Test";

                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"ID", DbType.String) { Value = id });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"Subject", DbType.String) { Value = subject });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"CreateDate1", DbType.String) { Value = createDate1 });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(@"CreateDate2", DbType.String) { Value = createDate2 });
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    TestModel item = new TestModel();

                    item.ID = reader["ID"].ToString();
                    item.Subject = reader["Subject"].ToString();
                    item.CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CreateDate"]);
                    item.UpdateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["UpdateDate"]);

                    dict.Add(item.ID, item);
                }
            }
            return dict;
        }
```